# How can I backup/restore an app (not just it's data) in iOS 10?

Tags: applications, backup, restore, ios

One of my apps got a big update with some mixed reviews, I'm interested in trying the new version, but won't do it if I can't roll back. For pre-iOS 9 systems, I heard you can backup ipa file from iTunes on PC, update the app on iPhone, and then if needed, overvrite back from iTunes and sync. But it doesn't work now - there's no ipa file for that app after iTunes sync.

What are my options? I've heard about programs like iMazing, but have a feeling that for iOS 10 it will just restore the app data and not the whole app version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an iCloud backup. iCloud backups are snapshots of the phone as it is. So you'll keep the old update and its data with an iCloud backup.

Do 1 right now and the other after the update.

After your testing, then you can over write that latest backup if need be based on your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean like a whole system restore using that iCloud backup? I had a feeling that restoring the system from any backup will download required apps from the app store in the process, the question is - wouldn't that be the latest versions?

Comment: Good question! Actually the iCloud backup saved the apps as files, just as they are. When you do that system restore it will re-download the apps back on your phone. But not from the App Store, but from the iCloud itself. The version that you had from the backup will be the same version when you restore the device. To further prove that, check the app store if you are going to restore that backup, you should see an update that is needed for that app.

Answer (score 1):

We periodically switch between Xcode versions. What we do for Xcode is drop to the command line and tar up /Applications/Xcode.app

Sometimes, we'll rename Xcode.app to be a different name (e.g. Xcode_8.3.3.app) and have multiple versions installed at once.

This has worked for us for Xcode. We have not tried it on any other application.