# Does an iPad backup restore the device exactly as it was?

Tags: backup, ipados

I'm using an older version of a critical app on a slightly older version of iOS - both have updates available but I can't risk problems if I update unless there's a way to roll back, which is not something appstore allows.

If I take a full backup of my device and then update apps+iOS, will restoring the backup revert all the apps to the exact versions previously installed? Is the backup a full byte for byte image of the device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, backups take the [general device settings and containers for each app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428) and store them only. The operating system and the [apps themselves](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302887/5472) do not backup.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

You can not roll back the iOS or iPadOS upgrade except in very special and sometimes time limited circumstances. Generally, you can never go back when you advance operating system on iPads.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly why I was asking... means there is no way to try the new app version and go back to an old 'image' like you could on a traditional TimeMachine type backup

Comment: @Mr.Boy when you restore the backup, it will download the exact version of the app that it previously had, so it should work for your purposes. But you're still probably better off using another device for testing this if it's so critical.

Comment: @Coxy are all old versions kept on the app-store though? Is that at the developer's discretion, or Apple's?

Comment: I'm sure not literally every old version is kept available for download, but most seem to be in my experience.